# mysql_connect() works PDO doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to connect to my database using PDO but i can't get it working. I get a 500 server error

MySQL version 5.0.83

> 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname
>   provided, or not known' inerror: Fatal error: Uncaught exception

Other error i get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out'

I changed the values in this example obviously. And yes they are the correct credentials. I can connect with Sequel Pro or other methods.

connection.php:

```
<?php

//Our MySQL user account.
define('MYSQL_USER', 'user');

//Our MySQL password.
define('MYSQL_PASSWORD', 'pass');

//The server that MySQL is located on.
define('MYSQL_HOST', 'host');

//The name of our database.
define('MYSQL_DATABASE', 'database');

/**
 * PDO options / configuration details.
 * I'm going to set the error mode to "Exceptions".
 * I'm also going to turn off emulated prepared statements.
 */
$pdoOptions = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
);

/**
 * Connect to MySQL and instantiate the PDO object.
 */
$pdo = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=" . MYSQL_HOST . ";dbname=" . MYSQL_DATABASE, //DSN
    MYSQL_USER, //Username
    MYSQL_PASSWORD, //Password
    $pdoOptions //Options
);
```

Registration.php

```
<?php 

require 'connection.php';
```

The strange thing is that on an older page of this website mysql_connect() is used.

> $db = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password); 
>   mysql_select_db($database,$db);

This works perfect with the exact same credentials.

It's hosted on a shared hosting and PDO is enabled on the server.
Shared Hosting: Blacknight

**I tried:**

- Not using $pdoOptions
- Not using define()
- Not using require and putting the new pdo code straight into the registration.php file
- running the script in the answers and now my mysql_connect() does a time-out and on my hosting i get a whitescreen.

> now: Fri, 15 Jan 2016 08:54:21 +0100 last changed:Fri, 15 Jan 2016
>   08:53:01 +0100 Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is
>   deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO
>   instead in connection.php on line 14
>
> Warning: mysql_connect(): Operation timed out in connectie.php on line
>   14 connection failed. Operation timed out

Comment: Do you use the exact(!) same defines for your mysql_* and PDO code?

Comment: Another possibility: the host is simply wrong, and `mysql_connect` fails for the same reason, but you're not actually checking for that, and when calling subsequent `mysql_` functions they do their ugly implicit behind-the-scenes best-guess connection which happens to work.

Comment: We'll have a hard time helping you here without knowing what the host should be and what it actually is and perhaps something about your DNS resolver.

Comment: http://mysql640int.cp.blacknight.com

Comment: To test deceze's idea please try `<?php $db = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password); or die('sudden death 1'); mysql_select_db($database, $db) or die('sudden death 2');` - though if true you should have gotten a warning message since you specified the connection resource in select_db.

Comment: The PDO connect code you've posted is exactly (again with an !) the code you're actually using? If there was e.g. a space between ´host=` and the hostname you'd get such an error. something like `http://mysql640int.cp.blacknight.com` would also be wrong.

Comment: Yes the code is exactly the same, i checked this like crazy before posting this question. I also checked for spaces & i didn't use http:// when using mysql hostname

Comment: That would mean `var_dump( MYSQL_HOST, gethostbyname(MYSQL_HOST)); die;` right before `$pdo = new PDO` should display the host name (only once) and the IP address of that server. Does it?

Comment: @VolkerK , yep it does string(29) "mysql640int.cp.blacknight.com" string(12) "172.16.4.101"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be the hosting. I put the exact same script on a different shared hosting : 'Combell' , i made a database on that hosting , i changed the credentials and the script works like a charm. So the problem is 'Blacknight'. Thanks for the help everybody.

Answer (score 2):

You said using the mysql_* functions the connection can be established, yet with he exact same parameters the PDO connection fails.
And it fails with `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses`....

So, abusing the "answers" section once again, I would like you to run the following script (only adjusting the defines) which will try both APIs.
It will also display the filemtime of the script; wouldn't be the first time some caching problem on a shared host caused the trouble ;-)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
// for testing purposes keep everything in one file
define('MYSQL_USER', 'localonly');
define('MYSQL_PASSWORD', 'localonly');
define('MYSQL_HOST', 'localhost');
define('MYSQL_DATABASE', 'test');

echo 'now: ', date('r'), ' last changed:', date('r', filemtime(__FILE__));


$db = mysql_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
if ( !$db ) {
    die( 'connect failed. '.mysql_error() );
}
if ( !mysql_select_db(MYSQL_DATABASE, $db) ) {
    die( 'select_db failed. '.mysql_error($db) );
}
echo 'mysql: ', mysql_get_server_info($db), "<br />\r\n";


$pdoOptions = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
);

try {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=" . MYSQL_HOST . ";dbname=" . MYSQL_DATABASE;

    $pdo = new PDO(
        $dsn,
        MYSQL_USER, //Username
        MYSQL_PASSWORD, //Password
        $pdoOptions //Options
    );
    echo 'pdo: ', $pdo->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_INFO), "<br />\r\n";
}
catch(Exception $ex) {
    echo 'PDO failed.', $ex->getMessage();
    var_dump($dsn);
    die;
}
```

Does the mysql_* part of the script get executed (printing the server version) while the PDO part fails again?

Comment: Oh, and while you're at it: _If_ the PDO part does fail, please also try with `define('MYSQL_HOST', '172.16.4.101');`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i added the error on the bottom of my question.

Comment: So, the mysql_* functions cannot connect to the MySQL server either. According to this [helpdesk entry](https://help.blacknight.com/entries/25026266-Where-do-i-find-my-MySQL-Database-details-) there is something called "internal hostname" - do you use this?

Comment: No i enabled external hostname, i tried both internal & external hostname. I also tried the direct IP-adress but nothing worked. I switched hosting and it worked instantly.